# how to move spring boot config file bootstrap.yml out of resource package

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using spring boot, the config file bootstrap.yml located at src/main/resources. When I build a jar file, the file bootstrap.yml was also included in the jar. That caused I can not modify the file once the jar was build.

So how should I move the bootstrap.yml file out of the jar, I tried remove it out and using -classpath to indicate the file, but it doesn't work. I tried command as following:

```
java -classpath /user/local/bootstrap.yml -jar spring_test.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place bootstrap.yml outside the jar simply, and startup the application with regular command such as

```sh
nohup java -jar xx.jar >nohup.log &
```

It will work as you wish, and config in this file is loaded with higher precedence than that one (also name as bootstrap.yml) inside the jar.